# GCC Flags for Alias Analysis and CSE

Tags: gcc, compiler-flags

I wish to perform Common Sub-Expression Elimination on my code, but I don't want compiler to perform Alias Analysis. I looked up on [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) at GCC Optimize options, I following flags on my code:

```
-ansi -fcse-follow-jumps -frerun-cse-after-loop -fgcse
```

But, no common sub-expressions were eliminated. [Link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5EhTzf) to godbolt.

Also, -O1 flags in 1st link mentions that it applies:

```
-fdefer-pop -fdelayed-branch -fguess-branch-probability -fcprop-registers -floop-optimize -fif-conversion -fif-conversion2 -ftree-ccp -ftree-dce -ftree-dominator-opts -ftree-dse -ftree-ter -ftree-lrs -ftree-sra -ftree-copyrename -ftree-fre -ftree-ch -fmerge-constants
```

Applying all of them as well don't eliminate number of sub-expression, but, applying -O1 does.

Which combination of flags perform CSE and which are responsible for Alias Analysis?

Comment: Out of curiosity,  why don't you want "Alias Analysis"?

Comment: I'm learning about what Code Optimizations and have read that alias analysis is to be performed to apply CSE on pointers. I want to know what happens when we don't and what happens when we do Alias Analysis.